# Android Eclipse ListView in AlertDialog hiding certain textviews when scrolling

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, textview, android-alertdialog

I have a list view inside of an alertDialog.  I populate my list view with a custom resourceCursorAdapter, and each row contains a title textView, date textView, and image.

Everything works well, except that it appears that when you scroll the listview, some of the date textView in some of the rows dissapear.  I have figured out why they are dissapear, just not how to fix it...  Some of the items aren't meant to display dates, so I have an if statement on bindview that determines if the dates should be shown or not.  This works for any list outside of an alertdialog, but it makes some dates that are meant to be shown dissapear.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

My code for the Alert Dialog and Listview:

```
itemSendPickerDialog = new Dialog(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select Item to Send");

        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) {


                }
            });
        AlertDialog sendOptionAlert = sendOptionBuilder.create();

                         sendOptionAlert.show();

                    System.out.println("ID is: " + iid + " and position is: " + position);
                    itemSendPickerDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchItemsByDate(id);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int i = R.layout.send_item_menu_row;
        MyListAdapter ia = new MyListAdapter(this, i, c);
        lv.setAdapter(ia);

        builder.setView(lv);
        itemSendPickerDialog = builder.create();
        itemSendPickerDialog.show();
```

And my custom listAdapter:

```
class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int i, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, i, cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_TITLE)));

        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        width = width - 150;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = title.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        title.setLayoutParams(params);

        String cat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY));

        if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes")) {   
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_datetime_holder);
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
        date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_DEP_DATE)));

        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_time);
        time.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_DEP_TIME)));

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
        if (iv != null) {
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_TYPE);

            String type = cursor.getString(index);
            if (type != null) {

            } else {
                type = "notes";
            }

            iv.setImageResource(getTypeResource(type));
        }

    }

    public static int getTypeResource(String type) {
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("flight")) {
            return R.drawable.airplaneicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("boat/ship")) {
            return R.drawable.boatshipicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("bus")) {
            return R.drawable.busicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("rail")) {
            return R.drawable.railicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("auto or other rentals")) {
            return R.drawable.caricon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("other transportation")) {
            return R.drawable.othertransicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("hotel")) {
            return R.drawable.hotelicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("resort")) {
            return R.drawable.resorticon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("bed & breakfast")) {
            return R.drawable.bandbicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("camp ground")) {
            return R.drawable.campgroundicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("vacation rental")) {
            return R.drawable.vacationrentalicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("other lodging")) {
            return R.drawable.otherlodgingicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("rail")) {
            return R.drawable.railicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("cruise")) {
            return R.drawable.cruiseicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("tour")) {
            return R.drawable.touricon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("dining")) {
            return R.drawable.diningicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("spa")) {
            return R.drawable.spaicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("class")) {
            return R.drawable.classicon;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("other activity")) {
            return R.drawable.eventicon;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.notesicon;
        }
    }

}
```

The specific code that makes the text disappear is in the bindview override:

```
String cat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY));

        if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes")) {   
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_datetime_holder);
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in ListView are recycled, when the row is disappearing at bottom it's emerging at the top of the list. It's not recreating, it's such optimization. In `bindView()` you're only setting current values.

You've forgotten about setting the view visible.

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_datetime_holder);
    if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes")) {   
        ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

It's worth to see: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: Most excellent.  Thank you very much for the answer and for the referenced reading!  I didn't realize the list item was literally recycled as is.  One question though... this fixed my problem, but why wasn't I experiencing the same problem using the same code but not having a listview inside of an alert dialog?  All of the textviews work just fine that way.  I did do a test and printed when the bindview method was being called, and its called repeatedly in the alertdialog (when scrolling), but one a few times initially when not in one (even when scrolling).

Comment: If adapter is the same then it should work similar. Maybe different data?